# Plot the curve $y^2 = (x^2 +12x +36)/(x^4 -4x^3 - 12x^2 - 32x 64)$

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, symmetry

Can you help me find the following to plot this curve,

$$y^2 = \frac{x^2 +12x +36}{x^4 -4x^3 - 12x^2 - 32x 64}$$

1. In Explicit Form
2. Find the Symmetry
3. X & Y intercepts
4. Vertical and Horizontal Assymptotes
5. Plot

I've been trying to figure this out but the professor only gave an example in the $y^2 =P(x)$ form but this is $y^2 = P(x) /Q(x)$ so I'm a little confused how to go about plotting this, thanks in advance to those that can help.

Comment: What does this mean $32x 64$? Are you missing a sign in there?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a typo, and you meant $x^4-4 x^3-12 x^2+32 x+64$.
In that case, the denominator is just:
$$(x-4)^2(x+2)$$
And the numerator is $(x+6)^2$.

Now can you solve the rest yourself?

Comment: Sorry about that, yes I am missing a sign there, it's supposed to be x^4 - 4x^3 - 12x^2 - 32x + 64

Comment: @TaraSalvador - you may want to double check the sign before the 32. If it's negative, the problem is much harder, and I doubt that was meant by the question.